# KnockoutJS with dynamically created partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm battling with a issue where i'm using a dynamic partial view bounding to a knockout list.

problem is that the viewmodel for the knockout list is not binding to the newly created dynamic view in the proper manor.

for example.
initial person control:

search for user "mark", ko array is populated

add another person control:

search for user "piet", nothing shows on the new control but the initial 
person grid is updated now to show piets results.

I've been researching how component-registration works but battling with this at the moment and could really use some help getting this to work.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html

below is the code:

**form:**

```
<div id="peopleDiv">
  @Html.Partial("_reconperson", @Model.ReconPerson)
</div>

<button id="addPerson">Add person</button>

<script id="personSearchTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td><label data-bind="text: EmployeeFirstName"></label></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script>
    $('#addPerson').on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        var div = $('#peopleDiv');
        var url = '@Url.Action("AddNewPerson")';    
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            div.append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

i have a actionresult sitting on my controller that will return the a partialview .

```
public ActionResult AddNewPerson()
{
return PartialView("_reconperson", CreateReconPerson());
}
```

**partial view:**

```
@model ReconPerson

@{
        var personSearchTxt = "personSearch" + @Model.ControlId;
        var personSearchDiv = "personSearch" + @Model.ControlId + "Div";
}

<input type="text" id="@personSearchTxt" />
<table id="@personSearchDiv">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
     <label>First Name</label>
   </th>                
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'personSearchTemplate', foreach: people }"></tbody>
</table>


<script defer="defer">
    $('#@personSearchTxt').keyup(function () {
        updateGrid('@personSearchTxt', true, "", "@personEmpId");
    });
</script>
```

**knockoutjs binding info**

```
var defaultColumns = {    
    EmployeeFirstName: ""
};

var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray([defaultColumns])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

update people observableArray:

```
function updateGrid(searchBoxName ) {

    viewModel.people.removeAll();
    var fullname = $('#' + searchBoxName).val();

    request = $.ajax({
        url: searchemployeeUrl + fullname,
        failure: function (error) { console.log(error); },
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                viewModel.people.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

hi so turns out i was been silly.

i just moved all the components into the partial view and then bound the view model to the div element and boom sorted.

```
@{ var peopleModel = "peopleModel" + @Model.ControlId;}
 var viewModel = {
            @peopleModel: ko.observableArray([defaultColumns])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("@personGroupDiv"));
```